# I can connect to my database through pgadmin, but I cannot connect to the database using terminal(psql)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I created a database using the GUI of pgadmin and it works well. I can connect to the server with my password. But when I want to connect to the database using psql in terminal, after I enter the password, it says

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "{username}"

I tried every possible password, but it's still not working.

Has anyone meet this issue before?

Comment: Can you add the exact and complete `psql` command you used?

Comment: Do you call the server "remote"? Or at localhost?

Comment: @sibert It is localhost.

Comment: @Shiva I only used    psql as command, and it asked me for password.

Comment: What is the settings for localhost in pg_hba.conf?

Comment: @sibert   TYPE: host  DATABASE: all       USER: all      METHOD: @authmethodhost@. I can't find a pg_hba.conf file, I can only find pg_hba.conf.sample. Are they the same?

Comment: "I can't find a pg_hba.conf file, I can only find pg_hba.conf.sample. Are they the same?". I do not think so. Have you looked in "etc /postgresql/version/main"?

Comment: @sibert Thank you so much for helping me. I've already connected to my database in terminal using `psql -U Postgres`. However, every time when I want to use `psql` command, I have to add postgres to the path. I'm still looking for the reason.